# Use peewee to flatten rows into columns

Tags: peewee

database backend is postgresqlon gcp.

I have a group of rows in a table that have an id. I am trying to flatten it out in rows with multiple column.

```
CREATE TABLE public.lines
(
    line_no int NOT NULL,
    line_content character varying(60) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer NOT NULL,
)
```

with data

```
(1,'content 1',parent1)
(2,'content 2',parent1)
(3,'content 3',parent1)
...
```

Trying to figure out a query to flatten the result to columns,

```
select line1, line2,line3
where parent='parent1'
```

How to accompolish this?? THANKS!!!!

Comment: Are the distinct values already known?

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting the result of the query to look like given your initial data example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work. Sql databases are tabular. You can't just arbitrarily return rows that are X-columns wide.

Your best bet is to use something like Postgres' `array_agg` which will return an array. Absent that, you could maybe use `group_concat` or something to produce a comma-separated list.

But this smells and is probably a horrible idea.

Just do the collapse/flatten in code if you must.

Answer (score 0):

If on PostgreSQL, you're really looking for a "pivot table" like thing. I'd look at the `crosstab` function (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tablefunc.html).) Which handles things of the format:

```
name value
A    1
A    2
B    3
B    4
B    5
```

and produces

```
A 1  2  3
B 3  4  5
```